# How do I move a Pervasive PSLQ database between servers

Tags: database, postgresql, pervasive

What is the easiest way to move a Pervasive PSQL database between two servers.

I can stop the database engines if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would stop the database engine at both sites. Copy all data (db files) from the first site to the second site and then start the second sites engine. If the folder is the same on both sites you are done. If not you have to "create" a new database (in PCC) on the second site that points to the datafiles you just copied.